# my website is not responsive anymore after using scope in the directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I  have used bootstrap to make the website it was responsive until I added below scope to the directive to make attribute for the defined pictureFrame element:

```
bootApp.directive('pictureFrame', function(){
    return{
        restrict:"E",
        templateUrl:"src/templates/directives/pictureFrame.html",
        scope:{
            picture:"@picture",
            border:'@border'
        }
    };
});
```

and this is how I used in the html page :

```
<picture-frame   picture="src/img/screen.jpg"  border="yellow"  >
</picture-frame>
```

After using these codes my website is not responsive anymore.
What could be the reason?

Comment: How do you mean 'not responsive'? If you mean that you can't dynamically change the values of `picture` and `border`, that's to be expected because you're binding on a literal value. You should use a scoped variable and bind on that, using `'='` instead.

Comment: How can you relate responsiveness with directive? you should add more explaination of your problem here. **Side Note** your html should be `<picture-frame   picture="'src/img/screen.jpg'"  border="'yellow'"  >
</picture-frame>`

Comment: I meant when I restore down the page the picture does not change the size so does not fit the pictureframe.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would like to have a bidirectional binding to your scope attributes. But you got a one way binding. If this is what you mean by no "more responsive" than just change your scope to:

```js
scope:{
            picture:"=picture",
            border:'=border'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KRNgE0RjmcG45JwwbByc?p=preview)?

Your directive would become this (using the code of the plunk):

```
app.directive('pictureFrame', function(){
    return{
        restrict:"E",
        templateUrl:"pictureFrame.html",
        scope:{
            picture:"=",
            imageClass:"="
        },
    };
});
```

The core elements of the controller:

```
$scope.index = 1;

var pictures = [
  "http://us.123rf.com/450wm/bagotaj/bagotaj1205/bagotaj120500016/13546752-coffee-cup-concept.jpg?ver=6",
  "http://us.123rf.com/450wm/peshkova/peshkova1208/peshkova120800337/14768439-young-man-and-business-tags.jpg?ver=6",
  "http://us.123rf.com/450wm/dimro/dimro1205/dimro120500005/13554732-coffee-cup-stylish-shape.jpg?ver=6"
];

var classes = ["yellow", "red", "blue"];

$scope.SetPicture = function() {
  $scope.picture = pictures[$scope.index - 1];
};

$scope.SetClass = function() {
  $scope.imageClass = classes[$scope.index - 1];
};
```

And you would set it like so:

```
<picture-frame picture="picture" image-class="imageClass"></picture-frame>
```

I've used image-class instead of border for ease of use.

PS: I see no use in providing a full identifier (`"=picture"`) if the name is the same.

PPS: Obviously the Plunk is an idealised version that would need real-world adaptation.